# how to pass list of objects that contains another list of object to wcf

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf

I have class contain list of object of another class.But when i send list of object to wcf method it coming about null.
here is my full code

here is my class :-

```
public class BOTHCCharges_DETAILS
{
    public String THCTerm { get; set; }
    public String FromNumberOfContainer { get; set; }
    public String ToNumberOfContainer { get; set; }
    public String _20_GP { get; set; }
    public String _20_HC { get; set; }
    public String _40_GP { get; set; }
    public String _40_HC { get; set; }
    public String Size { get; set; }
    public String Weight { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(List<BOTHCCharges_DETAILS>))]
public class List_BOTHCCharges_DETAILS
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<BOTHCCharges_DETAILS> THC_Details { get; set; }
}


//****    ICharges.cs 
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "AddTHCCharges")]
 String AddTHCCharges(BOTHCCharges_Master OBJBOTHCCharges_Master, List<List_BOTHCCharges_DETAILS> List_BOTHCCharges_DETAILS);

//***    Charges.svc.cs
 public string AddTHCCharges(BOTHCCharges_Master OBJBOTHCCharges_Master, List<List_BOTHCCharges_DETAILS> List_BOTHCCharges_DETAILS)
    {
      //code goes here.
    }
```

this is the json object i am sending through jquery ajax

```html
   {
  "OBJBOTHCCharges_Master":
  {
    "OriginLocationList":"[{\"CountryCode\":\"CHINA,\",\"LocationCode\":\"CNSHA,\",\"Currency\":\"AED,\"}]",
    "DesinationLocationList":"[{\"CountryCode\":\"SIN,\",\"LocationCode\":\"SGSIN,\",\"Currency\":\"AED,\"}]",
    "CargoWeight":"20,","CargoType":"Consol,General,","Taxable":true,"TradeType":"E"},
 "List_BOTHCCharges_DETAILS":
  [
        ["THC_Details",
           {
             "THCTerm":"","FromNumberOfContainer":"","ToNumberOfContainer":"","_20_GP":"","_20_HC":"","_40_GP":"","_40_HC":"","Size":"20","Weight":"Consol"
           },
           {
             "THCTerm":"","FromNumberOfContainer":"","ToNumberOfContainer":"","_20_GP":"","_20_HC":"","_40_GP":"","_40_HC":"","Size":"20","Weight":"Consol"
           }
        ],
    
        ["THC_Details",
            {
              "THCTerm":"","FromNumberOfContainer":"","ToNumberOfContainer":"","_20_GP":"","_20_HC":"","_40_GP":"","_40_HC":"","Size":"26","Weight":"Consol"
            }
        ]
       ]
}
```

jquery call

```html
var wcfServiceUrl = THC.urlAddTHCCharges;
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: wcfServiceUrl,
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                //fnBlockUI('operation in progress..', 'false', 'true', 'null', false);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.AddTHCChargesResult == 'SUCCESS') {
                    //$.showMessageBox({ content: "data has been saved successfully", title: 'My information' });

                    $.showMessageBox({ content: "Data has been saved successfully!", title: 'Save', OkButtonDoneFunction: function () {
                        location.href = 'Index'
                    }, type: 'question'
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $.showMessageBox({ content: data.AddDetentionChargesResult, title: 'Error', type: 'stop' });
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $.showMessageBox({ content: error.responseText, title: 'Stop', type: 'stop' });
            },
            complete: function () {
                //$.unblockUI();
            }
        });

*/
```

Class that container list of another class(class member) coming out null :-
[click to view for your  reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Cq0.png)
Do i need to serialised my class members or what ?.I am new to wcf.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON does not match your class.

This

```
public class List_BOTHCCharges_DETAILS
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<BOTHCCharges_DETAILS> THC_Details { get; set; }
}
```

means this

```
{ "THC_Details": [ { "THCTerm":"", … }, … ] }
```

not this

```
{ [ "THC_Details", { "THCTerm":"", … } ], … }
```

If the JSON does not match the class definition, you'll get a `null` as the binder is unable to deserialize the payload.

Comment: ["THC_Details",
           {
             "THCTerm":"","FromNumberOfContainer":"","ToNumberOfContainer":"","_20_GP":"","_20_HC":"","_40_GP":"","_40_HC":"","Size":"20","Weight":"Consol"
           },
           {
             "THCTerm":"","FromNumberOfContainer":"","ToNumberOfContainer":"","_20_GP":"","_20_HC":"","_40_GP":"","_40_HC":"","Size":"20","Weight":"Consol"
           }
        ],  is list of object of type BOTHCCharges_DETAILS